# How to update an already added SecIdentityRef to iOS app's keychain?

Tags: ios, keychain

I have a PKCS12 file in my app's document folder that contains one certificate and one private key.
I am able to open this .p12 file, extract the identity object and display some information thanks to Apple's documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-DontLinkElementID_10)

What I'm trying to do now is to store this Identity to the keychain so I can use it later. I've read a lot of different stuff on iOS Keychain and I'm having a hard time figuring out how it really works.

Apple's code seems to use a persistent_ref to retrieve the Identity stored in Keychain. But I don't really understand what this is... Is it a simple reference like a memory ref ? If that is the case what happens when the device reboots ?

Unable to find a lot more information about this I tried to do it differently by using the kSecAttr attributes.
The current code works fine to add Identity to keychain :

```
NSMutableDictionary * dictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];  

[dictionary setObject:@"LABEL" forKey:kSecAttrLabel];

[dictionary setObject:(id)newIdentity forKey:(id)kSecValueRef];

OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)dictionary, NULL);
```

But if I try to add it a second time I'm receiving a -25299 error which is "fine" since it already exists. I tried handling it by an update like this :

```
NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[searchDictionary setObject:@"LABEL" forKey:kSecAttrLabel];
[searchDictionary setObject:(id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(id)kSecMatchLimit];
[searchDictionary setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(id)kSecReturnRef];

NSMutableDictionary *updateDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[updateDictionary setObject:(id)newIdentity forKey:(id)kSecValueRef];

OSStatus status = SecItemUpdate((CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary,(CFDictionaryRef)updateDictionary);
```

With this code I get a -50 status error apparently because I have invalid parameters... Which one ? Why ? What can I do to update my keychain correctly ?

EDIT: As suggested I tried to delete the existing element prior to adding it but I'm stuck with the same status code (-50). Below is the code I tried:

```
NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [self setupSearchDirectoryForIdentifier:identifier];
OSStatus status = SecItemDelete((CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary);
NSAssert(status == noErr, @"Problem deleting current keychain item." );
```

setupSearchDirectoryForIdentifier simply create a NSDictionnary with the label of my item:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)setupSearchDirectoryForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {

    // Setup dictionary to access keychain.
    NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];  

    [searchDictionary setObject:identifier forKey:kSecAttrLabel];

    return searchDictionary; 
}
```

Thank you

PS : I'm developing on Xcode 4.2 / iPad 5.1.1

Answer (score 4):

Even if this is an old post, as I came up with similar issues very recently when working with identities in keychains (to be used for SSL client authentication), I am providing my own experience (with XCode 5.0.1) as support for this seems to be still very confusing.

**SecItemAdd** must indeed be used with very few keys. kSecValueRef (with the identity) is of course mandatory and optionally kSecAttrLabel. Using several other keys (e.g. kSecClass) resulted in silent failures, i.e. no error reported but the identity wasn't added. This was very confusing.

I didn't succeed either to use **SecItemUpdate** with such an identity. All my attempts resulted in a -50 error.

To be able to update an existing identity I deleted the existing identity using **SecItemDelete** and then added it with SecItemAdd. What was again confusing is that although the call to SecItemDelete returned a -25300 error back (errSecItemNotFound), it could be ignored as the identity was indeed deleted as it was possible to add it afterwards (using SecItemAdd) without an error.

Answer (score 3):

`SecIdentityRef`s, `SecKeyRef`s and similar `Sec...Ref` values are ephemeral representations of keychain items. They become invalid when the application exits or when their retain count reaches zero. They cannot be directly saved in persistent storage.

On the other hand, a persistent reference is a piece of `CFDataRef` that you can use to retrieve a particular keychain item later. You can store it in a file, in `NSUserDefaults`, or anywhere else you fancy. It will not become invalid when the application exits or when the device is rebooted. (However, a persistent reference may become invalid when the keychain itself is removed (i.e., when device is restored), when the item it refers to is deleted or when one of the item's identifying attributes is modified.)

Apple's sample code uses `SecItemAdd`'s second argument to retrieve persistent references to the items it adds to the keychain. This is then presumably stored in `NSUserDefaults`. Given the persistent reference, the app can later use `SecItemCopyMatching` to convert it to an `SecIdentityRef` that it can use.

Note that you don't have to use persistent references if you don't want to; if you wish, you can also choose to retrieve keychain items based on their label, or any other identifying attribute.

`SecItemUpdate` probably fails because a `SecIdentityRef` isn't a real keychain item. It is but a pseudo-item that is constructed when a public key and its associated private key are both on the keychain. As such, it doesn't make much sense to update it -- it doesn't own any attributes. All its properties are inherited from its associated `SecCertificateRef` (the certificate) and `SecKeyRef` (the private key). Updating these items instead of the identity should work. (But it is easier to simply create the item correctly: you can initialize any attribute by adding it and its value to `SecItemAdd`'s first parameter.)  Alternatively, you could try simply deleting the identity (`SecItemDelete`) before re-adding it to the keychain.

Comment: Just edited my question. I tried to delete prior adding the item but I still have the same status code even though I only have one element in my searchDictionary. Does not make much sense to me.